# How do I scroll a line with context into view

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtextedit, qtextcursor

I can scroll a line into view like so:

```
editor = QTextEdit()

scrollCursor = QTextCursor(editor.document())
scrollCursor.setPosition(pos)
editor.setTextCursor(scrollCursor) # You may want to save the previous cursor...
editor.ensureCursorVisible()
```

but this does minimal scrolling: The new position is often at the top or bottom of the widget and I have to scroll manually to see the context.

How can I make sure 5 lines of context are always visible?

Answer (score 1):

Just move the cursor around a few lines and call `ensureCursorVisible()` twice:

```
scrollCursor = QTextCursor(editor.document())
contextLines = 5

scrollCursor.setPosition(pos)
scrollCursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.Up, QTextCursor.MoveAnchor, contextLines)
editor.setTextCursor(scrollCursor)
editor.ensureCursorVisible()

scrollCursor.setPosition(pos)
scrollCursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.Down, QTextCursor.MoveAnchor, contextLines)
editor.setTextCursor(scrollCursor)
editor.ensureCursorVisible()

# Finishing touch: Select the line
scrollCursor.setPosition(pos)
scrollCursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.StartOfLine, QTextCursor.MoveAnchor)
scrollCursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.EndOfLine, QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
editor.setTextCursor(scrollCursor)
```